# Using a virtual machine for increased layer of privacy (w/ tor)?

Tags: virtualization, tor

One of my friends told me that running tor in a virtual machine Linux and then passing it through a proxy on the underlying Windows would provide in his words great security. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a more anonymous environment for your VM, then yes.  You can keep its software and browser plugins, etc, ... to a minimum and hence provide a more "vanilla" machine.

On top of that, if you'd prevent it from accessing the host machine, and sign in with a generic login (i.e: user and root).  Even when someone would compromise the machine, they'd have less information about the user using it.

If they compromise the machine completely,it's unlikely that they were to access the hosts' saved passwords, etc.  But it all depends on how well you keep both (or more) environments separate.

Comment: Thank you, will work on that. But what I don't understand, is this basically just adding an extra node before the Tor network (the underlying Windows in this case) or is the advantage the VM itself?

Comment: I think it's be safer to run the proxy from the VM itself; and connect through localhost:8118 (or so, this is privoxy's default).  Best is not to bother with your host OS at all.